# Why is date.ToString() displaying with time

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, winforms

I have a column with a `date` datatype in my sql-server database and I insert this into it `1999-12-23`. When i run the select query in my database is shows the date as `1999-12-23` but when i connect the database to my c# winform application and retrieve the date it displays as `1999-12-23 00:00:00` (i.e it displays date and time).

These are the codes i used

Create Table

```
CREATE TABLE Users.Personal
(
/*...Other Codes for the table this is the main problem*/
DateofReg date NOT NULL
)
```

Select query

```
SELECT * FROM Users.Personal
```

(This displays the date as `1999-12-23`)

Connection to Database

```
private void RetrievePersonalDetails()
{
    SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection("server=AMESINLOLA;" +
        "Trusted_Connection=yes;" +
        "database=Crm_Db;");
    myConnection.Open();

    SqlCommand myCommand = myConnection.CreateCommand();
    myCommand.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Users.Personal WHERE UniqueID='" + uniqueid + "'";
    myCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

    SqlDataReader myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();

    if (myReader.Read())
    {
        //Other codes inserting to textbox but this is the main problem
        txtDor.Text = myReader["DateofReg"].ToString();
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Empty");
    }
    myConnection.Close();
    myReader.Close();
}
```

(This displays the date as `1999-12-23 00:00:00`)

Why is the date displaying with time in the application but displaying well in the database and what can i do to display only date?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`myReader["DateofRef"]` seems to return a `DateTime` object. This internally stores the ticks of your date value (which includes time and milliseconds etc).

`ToString` applies a default formatting for your DateTime object.

you can also use 
     `DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString()` which will print only year, month and day.

The format though will depend on the current culture (`Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture`), `ToStrin` also takes a parameter called `IFormatProvider`, this can be set to any culture you want to specify how the date string should look like by using `CultureInfo...`

You can change the formatting by passing in the format to the ToString method.

Lots of examples can be found here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/zdtaw1bw(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: URL seems to lead to Deutsche msdn.

Comment: @Ela I dont understand how to apply

Comment: @PreciousTijesunimi your line of code, simply replace `myReader["DateofReg"].ToString();` with `((DateTime)myReader["DateofReg"]).ToShortDateString();` for example will do it. Of cause this is not very clean code, maybe cast it before you format it

Comment: @Ela `ToShortDateString` doesn't display in intelisense

Comment: you have to cast it to a DateTime object first.
var date = myReader["DateofReg"] as DateTime. or((DateTime)myReader["DateofReg"]).ToShortDateString(); should work, too

Answer (score 2):

While SQL Server has a type `DATE` which is a date without a time, .NET doesn't have anything like that in the core base class library.  So it uses a `DateTime` with the time set at midnight instead.

There are plenty of ways you can get a string containing just the date from a `DateTime`, but since `myReader["DateofReg"]` is boxing that `DateTime` as an `object`, you need to cast it first if you are going to do anything with it.  For example,

```
// Unbox the result by casting
DateTime dt = (DateTime) myReader["DateofReg"];

// Use a string formatter to get what you want
txtDor.Text = dt.ToString("d");

// or if you prefer, use this shortcut method
txtDor.Text = dt.ToShortDateString();
```

This should work just fine, but if for some reason you actually want a pure "date without a time" type that isn't just a string or a `DateTime` at midnight, you can use the `LocalDate` type from the [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org/) library.

Answer (score 1):

First solution:

```
txtDor.Text = myReader["DateofReg"].ToShortDateString();
```

Second one which I do not recommend:

```
txtDor.Text = myReader["DateofReg"].ToString().Substring(0,10);
```

Comment: I have the same problem, but cannot solve with this because there are some fields that are not dates, so it would break those ones.

Answer (score 0):

Try ToShortDateString instead of just ToString
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.toshortdatestring.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This will ensure the returned code will conform to a short datetime formatted DateTime object.

```
 txtDor.Text = myReader["DateofReg"].GetDateTime.Date.ToString("d"));
```

An example of this can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.date.aspx)

Comment: Throws an Error around `GetDateTime`

Answer (score 0):

This code will return the date in dd/MMM/yyyy format. For ex. 9th October 2013 will be in the format of 09/Oct/2013.

```
txtDor.Text = myReader["DateofReg"].ToString("dd/MMM/yyyy");
```